# Progress while loading data from .ser

Tags: java, serialization, progress-bar

I would like to build progress bar(Java) for my data loading. However my data is in .ser file as I read it as a serialized object. Any idea how should I present data loading progress in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html).  For further details, see [How to Use Progress Monitors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html#monitors) in the tutorial.